# Force use of copy constructor / Avoid use of copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, rvo

I'm currently writing a logging class (just for practice) and ran into an issue. I have two classes: The class Buffer acts as a temporary buffer and flushes itself in it's destructor. And the class Proxy that returns a Buffer instance, so I don't have to write Buffer() all the time.

Anyways, here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

class Buffer
{
private:
  std::stringstream buf;
public:
  Buffer(){};
  template <typename T>
  Buffer(const T& v)
  {
    buf << v;
    std::cout << "Constructor called\n";
  };
  ~Buffer()
  {
    std::cout << "HEADER: " << buf.str() << "\n";
  }
  Buffer(const Buffer& b)
  {
    std::cout << "Copy-constructor called\n";
    // How to get rid of this?
  };
  Buffer(Buffer&&) = default;
  Buffer& operator=(const Buffer&) & = delete;
  Buffer& operator=(Buffer&&) & = delete;
  template <typename T>
  Buffer& operator<<(const T& v)
  {
    buf << v;
    return *this;
  }
};

class Proxy
{
public:
  Proxy(){};
  ~Proxy(){};
  Proxy(const Proxy&) = delete;
  Proxy(Proxy&&) = delete;
  Proxy& operator=(const Proxy&) & = delete;
  Proxy& operator=(Proxy&&) & = delete;
  template <typename T>
  Buffer operator<<(const T& v) const
  {
    if(v < 0)
      return Buffer();
    else
      return Buffer(v);
  }
};

int main () {  
  Buffer(Buffer() << "Test") << "what";
  Buffer() << "This " << "works " << "fine";
  const Proxy pr;
  pr << "This " << "doesn't " << "use the copy-constructor";
  pr << "This is a " << std::setw(10) << " test";
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Copy-constructor called
HEADER: what
HEADER: Test
HEADER: This works fine
Constructor called
HEADER: This doesn't use the copy-constructor
Constructor called
HEADER: This is a       test
```

The code does exactly what I want but it depends on RVO. I read multiple times that you should not rely on RVO so I wanted to ask how I can:

1. Avoid RVO completely so that the copy constructor is called every time
2. Avoid the copy constructor

I already tried to avoid the copy constructor by returning a reference or moving but that segfaults. I guess thats because the temporary in Proxy::operator<< is deleted during return.

I'd also be interested in completely different approaches that do roughly the same.

Comment: 3. Write code that doesn't rely on whether RVO happens.

Comment: I guess thats the obvious choice. But I wanted to avoid a copy constructor that will most likely never be called.

Comment: Your class shouldn't be copyable or assignable anyway (it has a `stringstream` data member.) I really don't know what problem you're trying to solve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a contrived problem: Firstly, the code works whether RVO is enabled or disabled (you can test it by using G++ with [the `no-elide-constructors` flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fno-elide-constructors-162)). Secondly, the way you are designing the return of a `Buffer` object for use with the `<<` operator can only be done by copying<sup>†</sup>: The `Proxy::operator<<(const T& v)` function creates a new `Buffer` instance on the stack, which is then deleted when you leave the function call (i.e. between each concatenation in `pr << "This " << "doesn't " << "use the copy-constructor";`); This is why you get a segmentation fault when trying to reference this object from outside the function.

Alternatively, you could define a `<<` operator to use dynamic memory by e.g. returning a `unique_ptr<Buffer>`:

```
#include <memory>

...

std::unique_ptr<Buffer> operator<<(const T& v) const
{
    if(v < 0)
        return std::unique_ptr<Buffer>(new Buffer());
    else
        return std::unique_ptr<Buffer>(new Buffer(v));
}
```

However, your original concatenation statements won't be compilable, then, because `Proxy::operator<<(const T& v)` now returns an object of type `std::unique_ptr<Buffer>` rather than `Buffer`, meaning that this returned object doesn't have its own `Proxy::operator<<(const T& v)` function defined and so multiple concatenations won't work without first explicitly de-referencing the returned pointer:

```
const Proxy pr;
std::unique_ptr<Buffer> pb = pr << "This ";
//  pb << "doesn't " << "use the copy-constructor"; // This line doesn't work
*pb << "doesn't " << "use the copy-constructor";
```

In other words, your classes rely inherently on copying and so, if you really want to avoid copying, you should throw them away and completely re-design your logging functionalities.

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> I'm sure there's some black-magic voodoo which can be invoked to make this possible --- albeit at the cost of one's sanity.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! That sums it up pretty well. I think I'll stick with copying then